# How to set the action for a flow in ODL beryllium YANG UI?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, openvswitch, ietf-netmod-yang

I try to add flows to the switches via DLUX YangUI (using Beryllium). So, I go to the API opendaylight-iventory rev.2013-08-19 -> config -> nodes -> node ->table -> flow and start to add a flow like this (Preview): http://localhost:8181/restconf/config.. . { "flow": [ { "id": "1", "match": { "in-port": "2", "ethernet-match": { "ethernet-type": { "type": "0x0800" } }, "ip-match": { "ip-dscp": "0x2e" } }, "out port": "1", "flow-name": "mod1", "priority": "30000", "tableid": "2" } ] }

There is no subitem to set actions=ouput or something like that. Everytime I put a flow like that one above the instruction "out_port":"1" is ignored because the action is automatically set to "drop".

How can I set "actions" in the YangUI?

Answer (score 0):

Flow actions has to be embedded in below format. Refer this  [Opendaylight wiki](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Editing_OpenDaylight_OpenFlow_Plugin:End_to_End_Flows:Example_Flows) for flow samples with different set of match criteria & actions.

```
<instructions>
    <instruction>
        <order>0</order>
        <apply-actions>
            <action>
                <order>0</order>
                <output-action>
                    <output-node-connector>1</output-node-connector>
                    <max-length>60</max-length>
                </output-action>
            </action>
        </apply-actions>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
```

Comment: Thanks. How to set output actions to multiple ports in a flow. ?

Comment: A flow can have multiple actions, and to accommodate them repeat the <action> section with corresponding values.

Comment: It is not accepting if i give like this. "instruction": {
        "order": "0",
        "apply-actions": {
          "action": {
            "order": "0",
            "output-action": {
              "output-node-connector": "3",
              "max-length": "60"
            }
            
          }
         "action": {
            "order": "0",
            "output-action": {
              "output-node-connector": "2",
              "max-length": "60"
            }
            
          }
        }. Can you give me the correct template for this ?

Comment: Check this out. {
    "order": 0,
    "output-action": {
        "max-length": 65535,
        "output-node-connector": "openflow:224635992578792:1"
    }},
{
    "order": 1,
    "output-action": {
        "max-length": 65535,
        "output-node-connector": "openflow:224635992578792:10"
    }}

Comment: Yes Mohanraj, that's nice to get in touch with you via stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks :) It is working now. The template i used is:  "instruction": {
            "order": "0",
            "apply-actions": {
              "action": [
                {
                  "order": "0",
                  "output-action": {
                  "output-node-connector": "2",
                  "max-length": "65535"
               }
            },
            {
              "order": "1",
              "output-action": {
                "output-node-connector": "3",
                "max-length": "65535"
              }
            }
          ]
        }      }